# Goals with multiple events? Also is it possible to identify the event that completed the goal?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have more than 20 different product logins in my website, which are all outbound. If every login is considered a conversion, the number of goals in Google Analytics are falling short as Google gives only 20 goals.

Is there a way to consider all these login events as one goal, also should be able to view which product login is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use a common category and action for the events, and give the label a value of which product the login happened for.

For your goal configurations, you just need to configure the event goal with the common category and action. The label can be left blank.

This way you just use one goal for as many product logins. The key is to use a common cat and action. Downside is that you won't be able to see in your Goals report which login it was from, but you could find that in the Events report.